# Custom function in Excel for cell hyperlink creation

Tags: vba, excel

For example, if i have a complex functions like this one: `=IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2;D3:D$750;0)+ROW(A2);1;1));"")` i want to convert it into hyperlink which points to cell returned by that formula. And yeah, i know that it could be done by wrapping it with `=HYPERLINK("[file_name.xlsm]" & %formula%)` BUT, first of all, it looks very ugly and uncomfortable to read in the big sparse data, and second - it is very inconvenient to copy such data-blocks between Excel instances (and then replace filename).

So i wonder - is it possible to convert such output into cell-link for current file and sheet with readable text like "*D156*" in place of "*[long_file_name.xlsm]$D$156*"?

P.S. obviously i can make a custom function which returns current filename and put same formula into second argument of HYPERLINK func, but obviously it will be counter-effective, especially when i have huge chunks of data. So i want to wrap all this into 1 function...

P.P.S. Don't sure if this will be appropriate (it's kinda offtopic for this question), but it will be fine if the same functionality could be done with macro instead of custom function. So the macro should find all the duplicates inside of currently selected range and make hyperlinks (in cell with same offset on different sheet with offset +1, the next sheet after currently active) to next occurrence of every duplicate. The rest i can manage by myself.

---

UPD1:
Getting filename is not a problem, as i said in P.S., i can write a function like this:

```
Function GetCurFilename()
    GetCurFilename= "[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]"
End Function
```

but i still need somehow to send part of the first `HYPERLINK`'s argument as second one!

---

UPD2:
I guess it should be done like this:

```
Function MakeLinkArgs(cAdrs) As SomeType_interpreted_as_2_arguments
    If (cAdrs = "") Then
        MakeLinkArgs(1) = ""
        MakeLinkArgs(2) = ""
    Else
        MakeLinkArgs(1) = "[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" & cAdrs
        MakeLinkArgs(2) = Replace(cAdrs, "$", "")
    End If
End Function
```

So this func could be used like this: `=HYPERLINK( MakeLinkArgs( IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2;D3:D$750;0)+ROW(A2);1;1));"") ) )`

But still no luck finding type which could be interpreted as 2 arguments (don't sure if such exists at all)...

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you are asking, but I think that =CELL("filename") will help you.  This returns both the filename and the sheet.  Just extract the sheet name and file name from what this returns.  Also portable for cut/paste to other workbooks/worksheets.

Comment: Read the question till the end (at least to end of first P.S.), getting filename is not a problem, i need to propogate 1st arg as 2nd somehow for HYPERLINK func...

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn't found a way to send multiple arguments with single result from other function, but i found a side way to do what i want. It looks like a dirty hack to me, but i don't sure, maybe it's the way to do things in Excel VBA...

So first it's needed to add a public variable at the top of the Module:

```
Public sBuff As String
```

Next, these 2 functions should be added after public var declaration:

```
Function MakeCLink(cAdrs)
    If (cAdrs = "") Then
        MakeCLink = ""
        sBuff = ""
    Else
        MakeCLink = "[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" & cAdrs
        sBuff = Replace(cAdrs, "$", "")
    End If
End Function

Function sBuf() As String
    sBuf = "" & sBuff
End Function
```

And after compilation it could be used in formulas as such: `=HYPERLINK( MakeCLink(IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,D3:D$750,0)+ROW(A2),1,1)),"")), sBuf() )`

Yes, it's ugly, but works as magic for me =)